# Build fails due to timeout

Tags: opencv, travis-ci

I have a project that is a wrapper for `opencv` library, written in Rust.

In order to be able to test it I have to build `opencv` itself. Then I cache it but cold build time is higher than 50 minutes and job gets killed.

How could this timeout be increased? For example, I have 50min per job timeout, but I'd like to have 500 minutes per 10 jobs, so I can run my first cold start build for say 90 minutes and then run fast build for 10 minutes each.

I don't know if it's possible so I'm looking for any workaround. Here is my script which takes most of time:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eux -o pipefail

OPENCV_VERSION=${OPENCV_VERSION:-3.4.0}
URL=https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip
URL_CONTRUB=https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip
INSTALL_DIR="$HOME/usr/installed-${OPENCV_VERSION}"

if [[ ! -e INSTALL_DIR ]]; then
    TMP=$(mktemp -d)
    OPENCV_DIR="$(pwd)/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}"
    OPENCV_CONTRIB_DIR="$(pwd)/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}"
    if [[ ! -d "${OPENCV_DIR}/build" ]]; then
        curl -sL ${URL}  > ${TMP}/opencv.zip
        unzip -q ${TMP}/opencv.zip
        rm ${TMP}/opencv.zip

        curl -sL ${URL_CONTRUB}  > ${TMP}/opencv_contrib.zip
        unzip -q ${TMP}/opencv_contrib.zip
        rm ${TMP}/opencv_contrib.zip

        mkdir $OPENCV_DIR/build
    fi

    pushd $OPENCV_DIR/build
    cmake \
        -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF  \
        -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr \
        -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$OPENCV_CONTRIB_DIR/modules \
        -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=5.2 \
        -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX="" \
        ..
    make -j4
    make install && touch INSTALL_DIR
    popd
    touch $HOME/fresh-cache
fi

sudo cp -r $HOME/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/
sudo cp -r $HOME/usr/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: For those who downvote please explain, what do you dislike and what can I change in the question to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could this timeout be increased?

According to the [**Travis docs**](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Timeouts) it's not possible and the ***timeout is fixed*** to **50 min** (travis-ci.org) respectively **120 min** (travis-ci.com).

You could consider to upgrade the travis plan. Though, the real problem is *not* the timeout but the necessity to build a huge library before each build. Even tough caching improves the situation a bit, it's still bad.

There are some ways to to reduce the build time (per build) – what fits best for you depends on your situation of course.

#### A. PPA

If you are luckky and there's a **PPA** shipping a version of OpenCV you can [***use***](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-on-Standard-Infrastructure) that one. Travis runs Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.

#### B. Pre-build binaries

You always can build OpenCV your own and upload **pre-build binaries** to eg. a server or different Git repo. Then Travis can then download and install then there.

#### C. Docker

[**Docker**](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) is imo the *best approach* to this. Either create a custom ***Docker Image*** or use exiting ones (there are enough around). A good start to look for are [**DockerHub**](https://hub.docker.com/) and [**GitHub**](https://github.com/). In addition this way enables you to pack any further dependencies, compiler, … – simply everything you need.

#### D. Contact Travis

You can always [**drop an issue at Travis**](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues) and ask for an updated version of OpenCV.